# Sort array of strings by anchored search of second, third, etc word

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nspredicate

I mean a got an array with words like:

```
@[@"Hellobla", @"Hello Kitty", @"Hello Kitty Bla", @"Bla apukitty", @"Bla helkitty"]
```

i need to sort them like anchored of all words separated by space `@" "`.

if i'll type `"Hel"` - i will see `@"Hellobla", @"Hello Kitty Bla", @"Bla helkitty"`

if i'll type `"kit"` - i will see `@"Hello Kitty Bla", @"Hello Kitty"`

if i'll type `"bla"` - i will see `@"Hello Kitty Bla", @"Bla apukitty", @"Bla helkitty"`

etc :)

i do it in block returns array:

```
    // arrayWithData - All Words
    // searchWord - Text i try to search with
    // arrayToWrite - array to return with words
    // arrayToCompare - array with words already added whitch first NSPredicate *beginPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", //searchText];

beginMatch = [self.objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:beginPredicate];

   sortedWithSecondWordArray = ^(NSArray * arrayWithData,
                                  NSString * searchWord,
                                  NSMutableArray *arrayToWrite,
                                  NSArray * arrayToCompare) {

        NSString *space = @" ";

        for (__strong NSString *string in arrayWithData) {
            NSString *staticString = string; 
            while ([string rangeOfString:space].location != NSNotFound) {
                NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [string rangeOfString:space].location);

                NSString *keyword = [[string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""] trim];

                if (keyword.length > 0
                    && [keyword rangeOfString:searchWord options:NSAnchoredSearch].location != NSNotFound
                    && ![arrayToCompare containsObject:staticString]
                    && ![arrayToWrite containsObject:staticString]) {

                    [arrayToWrite addObject:staticString];
                }
                string = keyword;
            };
        }
        return arrayToWrite;
    };
```

It works, but if in my Array 2000 strings and it could be more than 10k. And its really awful. How to optimaze it?

Comment: i couln't understand your examples

Comment: The examples you gave sort by word counts in the order 1-3-2, not 1-2-3.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, then you want to match any string containing word that begins with your search string?

An `NSPredicate` with a regular expression can do that, using the `\b` word boundary anchor.

```
NSArray *data = @[@"Hellobla", @"Hello Kitty", @"Hello Kitty Bla", @"Bla apukitty", @"Bla helkitty"]; 

NSString *searchString = @"Hel"; // Change to other strings

NSString *anchoredPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*", searchString];

NSPredicate *anchoredPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES[cd] %@", anchoredPattern];

NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:anchoredPred];
```

It produces the results you are after, with the possible exception that it includes both "Hello Kitty" and "Hello Kitty Bla" in the results.

If that is not what you want, you might need to filter the result again to exclude strings that are substrings of other strings in the array.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly that i need. Regex is amaizing. And after that i sort by alphabet.    array = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying your search works (what it should do is not super-clear in the question), but you're concerned about speed.  Is it demonstrably slow, or you predict it will be?

The string count, not so much the byte count, is the factor for speed.  2000 is big-ish, but my intuition is that it will be quick enough using brute force.

Alternatively, optimizing search is a huge topic, but one can summarize most solutions as follows: build an index.  e.g. [Check out 'Tries'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: it works and it not so slow.. But it realy could be. In the accepted answer good solution is realy more "optimazed" then my one.